# Change font color on active tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, tabcontrol

I have a problem with my TabControl. I have various tabs set to be on vertical mode and they are a bit adjusted. Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image: tabcontrol]

And I wonder how I could change from the red to some light blue colour, and maybe change the gray background to a bit lighter.
I tried to follow another guy's advice I found via google on how to change the font to bold and tried this:

```
InitializeComponent();
tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);

private void tabControl1_DrawItem_1(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
            new Font(tabControl1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Aqua,
            new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
            tabControl1.Font,
            Brushes.Aqua,
            new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
    }
}
```

That did not work at all. Nor the color or font was bold or aqua.
Anyone has any ideas how to change it?
For some reason I'm having trouble to change the colors after changing the DrawMode properties to OwnerDrawFixed - which I need to have to be able to use these vertically aligned tabs.

Edit: I do not want to change the font/colors in the actual tabpage, just the tab on the left.

Answer (score 6):

The `tabControl1_DrawItem_1` method delivers what you want; the problem with your code is that you are not attaching it to the `DrawItem Event`. Just replace:

```
tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);
```

With:

```
tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem_1);
```

CLARIFICATION:

`tabControl1_DrawItem_1` assigns the same color to all the tabs (being selected or not). If you want to get a different color for selected/non-selected tabs, you would have to change this in the else part. Sample:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem_1(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
            new Font(tabControl1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Aqua,
            new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
            tabControl1.Font,
            Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed it and still don't see any bold text or aqua color.

Comment: @user3036459 If you open a new project, add a tabcontrol to it (called `tabControl1`), write `tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem_1);` in the Form Load event and include the `tabControl1_DrawItem_1` method, it would show  the fonts of the tabs both bold and in aqua color. Please include your whole code to know what might be the problem in your case.

Comment: Screw it, I can't get it to work. Luckily the default colors were gray and red and not like lime-green and pink haha.

Comment: @user3036459 ?! Please, add your whole code to your question if you want help. Most likely you are over-writing the behaviour of tabControl1_DrawItem_1 (presumably with tabControl1_DrawItem); but cannot help without seeing your code.

Comment: @JackGriffin You are welcome. In any case, note that this is not "a trick", just the expected way to perform the given actions in the draw event of that control. Additionally, this was the OP's idea, I merely fixed the code :)

Comment: @JackGriffin It never sounded bad and the used word doesn't matter, but the intention (your/future-readers' proper understanding of the situation). I (perhaps mis-) understood from your comment that this was some kind of not-well-documented behaviour; it is not, it is the standard approach to perform relevant modifications in the appearance of this control (similar ideas apply to any other Winforms control). Anyway, happy of having been helpful.

Comment: I get your point. I understand this is a standard approach. By 'trick' I didn't mean 'hack'.I meant it was an approach worth to remember in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

If your event does not fire change tab control draw mode to TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed. Also I suggest to change appearance of the tab control into one of the button type. It avoid problems with border line paint

Full code is as

```
public YourClassConstructor()
{
    this.tcRemontas.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    this.tcRemontas.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
    tcRemontas.DrawItem += TcRemontas_DrawItem;
}

private void TcRemontas_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;

    if (e.Index == tabControl.SelectedIndex)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
            new Font(tabControl.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
            tabControl.Font,
            Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 3, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
    }
}
```