# Coloring Tab when selected

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I can change the text of the tab, but not the color of the tab. I borrowed this from one of the users on stackoverflow.

I need to be able to change color outside of the TabControl1_Click event so I can call it at different times.
I need button on tab one to change tabs two color, I'm using TabControl1_Click as a test.

Private Sub TabControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Click

```
    ChangeColor(TabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1)

End Sub
```

Public Sub ChangeColor(Index_ As Int16)

```
    Dim font As Font = TabControl1.Font
    'this is the background color of the tabpage header
    Dim BoxBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Yellow) ' chnge to your choice
    '  Get the area of the header of this TabPage
    Dim HeaderRect As Rectangle = TabControl1.GetTabRect(Index_ - 1)
    '  Identify which TabPage is currently selected
    Dim SelectedTab As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(Index_ - 1)
    '  Create a Brush to paint the Text
    Dim TextBrush As New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
    '  Declare the text alignment variable
    Dim sf As New StringFormat()
    '  Set the Horizontal Alignment of the Text
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    '  Set the Verticle Alignment of the Text
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
    ' Declare a Font
    Dim newfont As New Font(TabControl1.Font.Name, TabControl1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular)


    SelectedTab.Text = "TESTx " + Index_.ToString


    TabControl1.CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(BoxBrush, HeaderRect)


    ' Draw the text
    TabControl1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(SelectedTab.Text, newfont, TextBrush, HeaderRect, sf)
    '  Job done - dispose of the Brush

    TextBrush.Dispose()
    BoxBrush.Dispose()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change font color on active tabpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311869/change-font-color-on-active-tabpage)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the color of each tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30039627/11683)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the color of each tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039627/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-each-tab)

Comment: Don't stray to far from the standard color theme or use a separate color for every tab.  Your users won't be able to tell which one is active at a glance.